# How do I mock the Doctrine PersistentCollection in PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, doctrine-orm, phpunit

Does anyone know how to mock a Doctrine PersistentCollection?

When I try and mock the class directly using PHPUnit and Mockery I get an exception that reads:

```
Mockery\Exception: The class Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection is marked final a
```

nd its methods cannot be replaced. Classes marked final can be passed in to \Moc
kery::mock() as instantiated objects to create a partial mock, but only if the m
ock is not subject to type hinting checks.

My research indicates that Mockery and/or phpUnit cannot use reflection once the methods are marked as final.

I then tried to create a stdClass and give it the methods an iterator would use (valid/current/next) but a foreach loop will not call these unless the class implements an iterator.

Thus, the following code does not work...

```
$this -> collectionMock = \Mockery::mock('PersistentCollection, Traversable');
$this -> collectionMock -> shouldReceive('rewind');
$this -> collectionMock -> shouldReceive('valid') -> andReturn('true');
$this -> collectionMock -> shouldReceive('next');
$this -> collectionMock -> shouldReceive('current') ->andReturn();
```

And throws seems to throw the following fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare Mockery_1670979900_PersistentCollection_Traversable::rewind() 
in C:\zendProject\zf2\vendor\mockery\mockery\library\Mockery\Generator.php(129) :
eval()'d code on line 43
```

Has anyone come up with a good way to mock this class

Comment: I updated my answer with a possible solution.  I've used the solution myself and gotten good results (although it was in a different context than yours).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doesn't seem like it's possible to mock a class that's been declared final. There may be some hope, however.  Since `PersistentCollection` implements both `Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection` and `Doctrine\Common\Collections\Selectable`, you can use Mockery to mock an object implementing both interfaces.

```
Mockery::mock(
    'Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection, Doctrine\Common\Collections\Selectable'
);
```

I've [used this to good effect](https://github.com/jeremykendall/flaming-archer/blob/develop/tests/FA/Tests/Event/Subscriber/PhotoSubscriberTest.php#L36) in one of my own projects.

As to why you can't mock a final class, this is the best I could find:

**Mockery**

The ability to mock final classes with Mockery is [limited](https://github.com/padraic/mockery#quick-reference):

> Again, the primary purpose is to ensure the mock object inherits a specific type for type hinting. There is an exception in that classes marked final, or with methods marked final, cannot be mocked fully. In these cases a partial mock (explained later) must be utilised.
>
> ```
> $mock = \Mockery::mock('alias:MyNamespace\MyClass');
> ```

Search the linked page for 'final'.  You'll find all the documentation I could find.

**PHPUnit**

Attempting to mock a final class in PHPUnit [throws an exception by design](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-mock-objects/blob/master/PHPUnit/Framework/MockObject/Generator.php#L699-L706).