# Getting errors in PHPUnit when trying to mock Doctrine 2 Entity Repository

Tags: php, unit-testing, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine

I'm building a ZF2 application with Doctrine 2, and am trying to test it by using mock objects. The original action I'm trying to test is as follows:

```
public function indexAction()
{   
    $title = 'File Types';
    $this->layout()->title = $title;

    $em = $this->serviceLocator->get('entity_manager');

    $fileTypes = $em->getRepository('Resource\Entity\FileType')
        ->findBy(array(), array('type' => 'ASC'));

    return array(
        'title' => $title,
        'fileTypes' => $fileTypes
    );
}
```

In my test, I use the following method to create mocks of the entity manager and the FileTypes entity repository:

```
public function mockFiletypeResult($output)
{
    $emMock = $this->getMockBuilder('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    $repositoryMock = $this->getMock('Resource\Entity\FileType');

    $repositoryMock->expects($this->any())
        ->method('findBy')
        ->will($this->returnValue($output));

    $emMock->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getRepository')
        ->will($this->returnValue($repositoryMock));

    $this->getApplicationServiceLocator()->setAllowOverride(true);
    $this->getApplicationServiceLocator()->setService('Resource\Entity\FileType', $repositoryMock);
    $this->getApplicationServiceLocator()->setService('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager', $emMock);

}
```

The above code is based on what I read in [this post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20829791/how-do-i-mock-the-doctrine-persistentcollection-in-phpunit).

The problem is, when I run the test, I get the following error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mock_FileType_39345bde::findBy() in /path/to/test`. What am I doing wrong? I've looked around a bunch but can't seem to figure out the problem.

EDIT: I had originally written that the error message was complaining about the unidentified findAll() method, when it was actually findBy().

EDIT 2: I have since tried adding a new method to my entity repository, as follows:

```
public function getFileTypes()
{
    $query = $this->_em->createQuery('SELECT t
        FROM Resource\Entity\FileType t
        ORDER BY t.type ASC, t.extension ASC');

    return $query->getResult();
}
```

I then tried replacing the findBy method with getFileTypes in my controller, and stubbing out the getFileTypes in the mock. Same problem: it says it can't find the method.

One more thing: not sure if it matters or not, but I'm using PHPUnit version 3.7. For some reason I thought the 4.x versions didn't work properly with ZF2. Should I upgrade?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't use `getMockBuilder()` on your repository, it will expect you to stub any methods that are called.  If you use `getMockBuilder()`, it will automatically replace all functions with a dummy implementation that returns `null`.

So you can either use the mock builder

```
$repositoryMock =
    $this->getMockBuilder('\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository')->getMock();
```

or stub out the `findBy()` function that is being called elsewhere

```
$repositoryMock->expects($this->any())
    ->method('findBy')
    ->will($this->returnValue(null));
```

See more: https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html

**EDIT:**

I just noticed that you are mocking your entity, but you need to be mocking either your repository or Doctrine's.  See my edited comment above.  If you keep the `findBy()` method you can simply mock the *EntityRepository* class.  If you had your own (such as *Resources\Repository\FileTypeRepository*), you could mock that instead.

Also, you might need to put the `\` at the beginning of your MockBuilder calls so they are properly namespaced.

Comment: I just tried both of your suggestions (assuming of course you meant to say `$repositoryMock = $this->getMockBuilder('Resource\Entity\FileType')->getMock()` :). I still get the same result. I also tried adding a new method to the repository (see the edit in my original question), but still no dice.

Comment: I did recently have some trouble with this, where I had to mock the `find()` method, not on the mocked repository but instead on the mocked entity manager.  However, there is no `findAll()` on the entity manager.  When you tried the different method, did it still complain about `findAll()`?

Comment: Oh snap! I put the wrong error message in my question! The original message was that it couldn't find the findBy method. I had then tried changing over to findAll, but got the same result--I accidentally copied out the wrong code from my console window!

Comment: Updated my post, I think I discovered the issue - you need to mock the entity repository that contains the `findBy()` function, not your entity.

Comment: Of course! In hindsight it's such an obvious solution, but I just didn't see it. Thank you!

Comment: No problem - it was so obvious that we both missed it.  Glad it works now!